# Ampscript function to remove the comma from a number greater than 1000

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, content-builder, data-types

I have an API call that is passing over what should be a number as a text field. If the number is over 1000, the value is being sent with a comma (e.g. 3,000 instead of 3000). Salesforce will not recognize this as a number if the comma is there, so any conditional logic I try to do on that field breaks (i.e. "Display content block X if Field > 1000).

Obviously the best solution would be to have the API developers fix the data they're sending, but they don't want to do that. Is there an ampscript function I can use to take the comma out of the number and convert it to a numerical value? I've tried FormatNumber() and AttributeValue() with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a simple [Replace](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Replace.htm)?

```
SET @Number = Replace(@CommaNumber,’,’,’’)
```

This will strip all the unnecessary, in your number. And you don’t have to typecast your variable, as it will simply work if it meets the criteria of being a number.

Comment: That works, thank you!